# PHP slow if requested with AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, slowdown

I made a simple Webpage with an empty form Tag. This Tag is filled with the response of an AJAX request. The request asks a PHP script for data. This script returns its execution time. Now there is something really odd. If I type in the address by hand then the script tells me

`<!-- Duration: 0.8 milliseconds (~1242 pages per second) -->`

But if I use the build-in network request logger of Chrome (for watching what has been loaded) then I got this

`<!-- Duration: 52.7 milliseconds (~19 pages per second) -->`

Any ideas why it is 80 times slower?
I repeat: Same script, same parameter, identical response (but the duration time of cause), same server, different request types: AJAX and browser address line.

```
<?php
class AbstractModule
{

    final function __construct(..)
    {
        // for measuring creation time
        $this->starttime = microtime(true); 
    }

    public final function return_duration()
    {
        $duration = (microtime(true) - $this->starttime) * 1000;
        return "\n<!-- Duration: " . number_format($duration, 1, '.', '') . " milliseconds (~" . number_format(1000 / $duration, 0, '.', '') . " pages per second) -->";
    }

}

$demo = new AbstractModule();
// doing very much :)<
echo $demo->return_duration();
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post your code here for us to see where is it taking time?

Comment: I don't think you know more than before my post. It is all ways at the beginning and at the end. What can I say more than that?

Comment: Hmmm seems to be a random problem. Today everything is fine again. Perhaps page 1 made the Apache too busy to send out the AJAX page in time. But that's only a wild guess ... It was repeatable over hours.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use sessions? The difference might be that the ajax request restarts a session each time, because you don't send any cookies along.

Otherwise, I suggest you break out a debugger and track down the culprit.

Comment: AJAX requests do contain all cookies a normal request would contain, too.

Comment: It was a random untraceable problem :/ and it never came back.